# Laravel - redirect to controller

Tags: php, controller, laravel

I keep getting: `Unknown action [HomeController@showHome]`

Route:

```
Route::get('/', ['before' => 'checkUserFilter'], 'HomeController@showHome');
Route::get('/createUser', 'UserController@createUser');
```

Filter:

```
Route::filter('checkUserFilter', function() 
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
    {
        return Redirect::action('UserController@createUser');
    }  

});
```

Controller:

userController

```
public function createUser()
{
   // removed everything else, the return redirect action isn't working.

  return Redirect::action('HomeController@showHome');
}
```

homeController

```
public function showHome()
{
    return View::make('home');
}
```

When a user loads the webpage, the filter checks if he's a guest or not, if he is, go to the createUser method in UserController.php. It creates the user, but it doesn't redirect back to HomeController. How can I stop the above error so it redirect back to the HomeController?

I also have another question: What would be a better way to place the return redirection action, besides in the method? I would like it if I can use this same method for multiple things, for example create a user in the admin control panel.

Comment: Does your `HomeController` have a method called `showHome`?

Comment: Yes, edited question for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your route to HomeController is where the problem exists.

Here are two possible solutions:

Solution 1: routes.php

```
Route::get('/', array('before'=>'checkUserFilter', 'uses'=>'HomeController@showHome'));
```

Solution 2: HomeController.php

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->beforeFilter('checkUserFilter');
}

//showHome
```

Haven't tested it, but hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks, that worked! Can you explain the "uses" keyword? I've tried to search for what it actually does to understand it better, but can't find anything.

Comment: It's just to tell route which controller to use. For more info, please have a look at "Attaching A Filter To A Controller Action" in http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: Question, I like Solution 2 because it's using Controllers. However, when using this, the __construct doesn't seem to run.